# Return field with matching ids to gallery

Tags: collections, powerapps

Basically, I want to iterate through a column in a collection and if the current value equals an ID from another collection simply return it.

```
ForAll(availableCustomers, LookUp(customer, customerID = custID))
```

This code used to work fine with my old sources, however after making some necessary changes it seems to only return blank records. Weird thing is power apps is even returning the correct amount of records, the are just unfortunately blank.

[collection I am iterating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCaSx.png)

[collection I am filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJdq6.png)

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiR3E.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like, replacing it with your own column and data names:

```
Filter(availableCustomers, customerID in theOtherCollection.CustomerID)
```

Let me know how it works for you.